# .htaccess Question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a login script using PHP. The variables for login in and out are

log.php?do=in and log.php?do=out

I would like to change this to log/in and log/out if possible.

Im really struggling to understand .htaccess and the rewriting at the moment ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^log/(in|out)$ log.php?do=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic format of what you want is (example found at [this site](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html))

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^old\.html$ new.html
```

The caret, ^, signifies the **start of
an URL**, under the current directory.
The dollar sign signifies the **end
of the string** to be matched.
The backslash is to escape the dot, which is a special
character.

You might also want to look at some [mod_rewrite tutorials](http://www.blogstorm.co.uk/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/), there are some well written ones if you look around enough.