# .htaccess - Pretty User Profile URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make my user profiles 'pretty' as it were. Here is the regular URL:

user.php?user=UserName

I want this to become:

user/Username

Please help :) Im a .htaccess newbie.

Comment: You already asked something *very* similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930420/htaccess-question

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904075/using-mod-rewrite-to-change-url-with-username-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these directives:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)$ user.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This rule rewrites any request with a URL path of the form `/user/`*`foobar`* internally to `/user.php?user=`*`foobar`*.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)$ user.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```