# How to get rid of backslashes at the back of a url?

Tags: php, url, redirect, url-rewriting

Ok actually im not really sure whether the last string in a url is a file or a directory...
for example facebook.com/skaloot. is skaloot a file (facebook.com/skaloot.php) or a directory? (facebook.com/skaloot/index.php) and how do i get rid of ".php" or "/"...

Thank you...

Comment: \ → "backslash", / → "slash". Also, the term you're looking for is "pretty URLs".

Comment: It doesn't have to be either.

Comment: if facebook uses modrewrite (and i think they do) skaloot may be just a string passed to a totaly different file on their server. i.e. it also could be facebook.com/handler.php?q=skaloot or facebook.com/another.php?s=skaloot ..... the combinations here are endless and there is no way to find out

Comment: `/skaloot` is the path segment of the URL. In other words, neither a file nor a directory, just a string.

Comment: thanx for replying guys...ok lets just say that skaloot is a file...how do i get rid of ".php"...

Comment: Are you parsing the URLs in PHP or are talking about serving files from your own server without the .php?

Comment: @deceze owh...so i can just add/alter the url by adding **/skaloot** at the end of it?

Comment: You have tagged your own question with `url-rewriting`. Have you researched in this direction? You'll need to employ some sort of URL rewriting, but what exactly you need to do depends on whether the target is a file or a folder or neither. It also depends on your web server.

Comment: A URL is just that, a URL. Arbitrary text. It does not have to correspond to any physical file or folder on the server. In Facebook's case, it most certainly doesn't. What do *you* want to do?

Comment: @Treffynnon i want my user to have their own "skaloot.my/name" without the ".php" or "/" at the back...

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess - Pretty User Profile URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930789/htaccess-pretty-user-profile-urls)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Parsing URLs

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/example.php';
$url = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '.'));
var_dump($url);
// output is: string(30) "http://www.example.com/example"
```

### URL Rewriting

In your .htaccess file you can use mod_rewrite to rewrite pretty URLs to their actual destination.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# If the URL does not already exist as a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^example$ /example.php [QSA,L,NC]
```

The above will direct traffic hitting http://www.example.com/example to your example.php script.

Obviously replace example.com with your domain.

### Subdomain option

Another option is to give your users a subdomain each. simon.sklaloot.com for example. I have previously answered a question pertaining to this: [Create subdomains on the fly with .htaccess (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php/586160#586160)