# Reformat web URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For the lack of better words, my title is not the best, but I will describe to you more of what I am looking for. I just got my website setup to strip file extensions (website.com/home) and now I just had a few questions on how to incorporate this procedure throughout my whole site.

**My main question is**, when I view a users profile on my site, instead of calling it to the page by website.com/**profile?id=1**, I would like to know how I can call it simply by typing website.com/**profile/1**. If anyone has any advice that would be great!

Comment: Lookup .htaccess and rewrite rules :) plenty of examples online.

Comment: You can do this without .htaccess. Search PHP routing system.

Comment: I had it learnt in a matter of hours just by watching a [few videos](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=URL+rewriting+php).

Comment: @webnoob, I used it only "For the lack of better words". And, If I knew what to search for, I would have.

Comment: This question has been asked a thousand times (if not more). e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930789/htaccess-pretty-user-profile-urls).

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use a rewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/?$ /profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

A few resources for learning about rewrites:

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-basic-examples.html
http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/
http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/

Comment: I plugged this in and it didn't work, it actually just killed the style sheet.

Comment: Well, that should work...so you must be doing something wrong. Make sure you're putting it in the root .htaccess file, and that `RewriteEngine on` is only called once.

Comment: @Nick, you're forgetting to include the appropriate conditions: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` (I'll suggest the edit)

Comment: @MikeAnthony those conditions shouldn't be required, surely there wouldn't be directories called `/profile/1/`, `/profile/2/`, etc already created.

Comment: @Nick: yes, but if they're not included (in fact, just the `!-f` directive), the style sheets will rewrite as well... Standard rules.

Comment: If the browser is trying to request the style sheets using the path /profile/[0-9]+/? then something has already gone very wrong. I agree with Nick: I don't think those RewriteCond directives are necessary in this case.